# Can't select "The StackExchange Network" as parent site on Chat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, network-profile

On your StackExchange chat profile (chat.stackexchange.com/users/`<id>`/`<name>`<sup>1</sup>), you can change the parent site your chat profile is linked to by hitting the 'Change' link.

You can also select "The StackExchange Network", but when you choose it, nothing happens. Could this be fixed please?

<sub>1: You can get to there via your avatar on chat:</sub>

[image]

Comment: It says page not found when I click on it.

Comment: so dumb... (me that is)

Comment: I see network profile, not user profile. None of the links there seemed to give any change options.

Comment: @SeanTilson sorry, I wasn't clear - again. I added a picture to clarify ;) now let's clean up these comments.

Comment: I think this is by design, and not a bug. Because the Stack Exchange Network is not a Q&A site. You have to pick a Q&A site like Superuser, or Stackoverflow, or something else. But it shouldn't even be coming up as a selectable item if you can't use it as parent user profile. This is also something of a bad design, ideally if you are not allowed to select something, it shouldn't be popping up either.

Comment: That's the M.C. Hammer site - you can't touch it. _(I'll get my coat)_

Comment: @Lix My "answer" was in that there is nothing to be done about it. This is how it is by design. It has to be a Q&A site, and your network profile is not one of them. I read the original posters question purely as a "why" question, not as a demand for a major design change. So that's what I was offering, an explanation of why this is. I'm afraid I am not able to influence the SE development or change this behavior of the site by my own. I'm not sure what you expect me to do, provide a hack or a workaround?

Comment: @CamilStaps I have edited your question and added my own screenshots. You ask if this can be fixed. But may I ask you, what outcome do you expect? Do you expect to be able to set the "Network" as your parent profile, or you just expect it not to show up in the filter as it's not a valid selection? Please re-phrase your question to get rid of the ambiguity.

Comment: @TimPost Did you just revert my edit or did I just forgot to save it... lol.

Comment: @Sammy nobody "reverted" your edit, [it was declined](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25382) because you changed the question too much.

Comment: I see. Oh well, never mind then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to have your account associated with an actual site, because:

- You don't actually have rep on Stackexchange.com itself, merely an aggregate sum of all sites
- Chat won't let you talk without a profile having sufficient privileges.

It shows up because "Stack Exchange Network" is returned by our site search, but it's not a valid target for a chat association. You'll need to associate your chat account with one of the sites where you're active.

Could be worth not showing that, but it .. well .. hadn't confused anyone up to this point :)

Comment: This is a two part problem. One is that you can't set the network profile as your parent user, for reasons you have already explained. The other part is the filter result. Yes, removing "Stack Exchange Network" from the filter results could be considered as solution, even by @Lix.